# RXJS: How can I generate a stream of numbers at random intervals (within a specified range)?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I want to use RXJS to set up an ORDERED data stream that emits a number at a random interval (say every 1-5 seconds) which I want to use as a time-randomized data source for testing other parts of RXJS. The following code is generating the items in a random order (due to the delay) but I would like the order preserved only the time randomized.

```
function randomDelay(bottom, top) {
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) ) + bottom;
}

var source = Rx.Observable
  .range(1, 10)
  .flatMap(function (x) {
    return Rx.Observable
      .of(x)
      .delay(randomDelay(1000,5000));
  })
 .timeInterval();

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
     $("#result").append('Next: ' +  JSON.stringify(x) +  '<br>');
  },
  function (err) {
     $("#result").append('Error: ' + err);
  },
  function () {
     $("#result").append('Completed');
  });
```

is giving me variants of the following output:

```
Next: {"value":1,"interval":1229}
Next: {"value":2,"interval":321}
Next: {"value":4,"interval":645}
Next: {"value":5,"interval":28}
Next: {"value":9,"interval":728}
Next: {"value":10,"interval":269}
Next: {"value":3,"interval":107}
Next: {"value":6,"interval":265}
Next: {"value":8,"interval":1038}
Next: {"value":7,"interval":199}
```

Answer (score 11):

I just used this question as my base to another and had to update it to RxJs 6 if anyone is interested.

```js
const { range, of } = rxjs;
const { concatMap, delay } = rxjs.operators;

range(1, 10).pipe(
  concatMap(i => of(i).pipe(delay(1000 + (Math.random() * 4000))))
).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`.

Documentation here:
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/concatmap.md

```
var source = Rx.Observable
  .range(1, 10)
  .concatMap(function (x) {
    return Rx.Observable
      .of(x)
      .delay(randomDelay(1000,5000));
  })
 .timeInterval();
```

Comment: FWIW, I had to remove that `.timeInterval()` in the last line.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest dividing this problem into two subproblems: i) emitting at random intervals and ii) generating random values. The first problem could be solved by a suitable custom RxJS observer (that is what [crazyObservable](https://github.com/cszredwan/crazyObservable) is meant to do); the second problem can be solved by a custom subscription to the crazyObservable.

crazyObservable has three parameters: totalNumberOfEmissions, timeInterval and totalNumberOfTimeIntervals; it returns a custom observable that emits randomly totalNumberOfEmissions over the totalNumberOfTimeIntervals.

To get your desired behavior, set totalNumberOfEmissions, timeInterval, and totalNumberOfTimeIntervals at your willing. This [Marble diagram](https://github.com/cszredwan/crazyObservable/blob/master/crazyObservableMarbleDiagram.png) can be of help.

```
var oneHourRandomTenHundredRequisitions$ = crazyObservable(1000,1000,60*60);

let testComponent1 = oneHourRandomTenHundredRequisitions$.subscribe({
next() { <a call to your random generator> } ,
error() { <your custom error call> },
complete() { <your custom complete call> }
});
```

Comment: Hi please try not to provide link only answers. If the link is invalid, the answer will not help anyone. If you know of parts from the link that can solve the issue, please include it as part of the answer, and reference the website.