# Rx randomInterval

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I need a way to create randomInterval stream(similar to `interval`).

It should produce stream like this:

```
V-V-----V--V-V-VVV-V
```

When `interval` creates a stream like:

```
V--V--V--V--V--V--V--V
```

How can I achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question was already asked here. Cf [RXJS: How can I generate a stream of numbers at random intervals (within a specified range)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060681/rxjs-how-can-i-generate-a-stream-of-numbers-at-random-intervals-within-a-speci)

You should be able to make up an answer to your problem from that only if you have a finite number of random intervals that you want to generate though.

```
var source = Rx.Observable
  .range(1, 10)
  .concatMap(function (x) {
    return Rx.Observable
      .of(x)
      .delay(randomDelay(1000,5000));
  })
 .timeInterval();
```

For a version with infinite generation of random intervals:

```
function sum(a,b) {return a+b}

var source = Rx.Observable.of(1)
 .flatMap(x => Rx.Observable.of(x).delay(randomDelay(bottom,top))
 .repeat()
 .scan(sum, initialNumber)

 function randomDelay(bottom, top) {
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) ) + bottom;
}

 source.subscribe(function(x){console.log(x)})
```

PS : if you are using Rxjs v4 or lower, the answer proposed by the OP is in my opinion the best answer as it uses a operator specialized to this purpose. If you are using RxJS v5, currently in beta, I could not find the operator `generateWithRelativeTime` in the distribution, so you can resort to the answer mentioned here.

Comment: Hm, actually my question is a little bit different. `concatMap` doesn't work for infinite streams. I tried to replace `range` with `repeat` in you sample and it doesn't work

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/rLu3kwuL/ and http://jsfiddle.net/ytv90sjv/ for an example of infinite generation od random intervals.

Comment: yep, It works but it's non trivial. StackOverflow is about sharing you experience. Please change you answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Please, look at the other answer. What do you think about it?

Comment: I never used that operator so I think the answer is helpful and illustrate an other way to do the same thing. Actually I think you should accept your own answer, it is probably the simplest solution. I'll gladly upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

I finished with solution below:

```
    rx.Observable.generateWithRelativeTime(
        1,
        function (x) { return true; },
        function (x) { return x + 1; },
        function (x) { return x; },
        function (x) { return math.randomInt(100,500); }
    ).timeInterval()
    .do(console.log).subscribe();
```