# RxJava: How to to execute a task every 5 seconds only if the last task finished

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, reactivex

I'm using RxJava. I have to execute a specific task every 5 seconds. That works perfectly by using the "Observable.Interval" method.
However, I also have the following constraint: A new task must not be executed if the last task didn't finished. In this case, the new task need to be executed only when the last one finished.

I can't figure out how to do this simply with RxJava.

All ideas would be really appreciated ^^

Thanks for reading.

Comment: you will have to use concatMap.This sol is in rxjs though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060681/rxjs-how-can-i-generate-a-stream-of-numbers-at-random-intervals-within-a-speci

Comment: Is it 5 seconds after the previous run finished or approximately in every 5 seconds?

Comment: just fixing my answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you call `interval` a worker is selected that corresponds to a single thread from the given scheduler (default is `computation`):

```
Observable
    .interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap(n -> task());
```

or if nothing is returned by the task:

```
Observable
   .interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
   .doOnNext(n -> task());
```

This means that for every 5 seconds there will be a run but if the task takes 5 or more seconds then the tasks will be running continuously (but not concurrently).

If you want to ensure a gap between running tasks then you could skip tasks based on the time of the finish of the last task. I can flesh that out if you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Indeed, I need to ensure the gap between the running tasks. Ideally I was searching for a pure "reactivex" solution to this problem. However, maybe in practice adding specific code to skip the task based on a timestamp as you advice is the simplest way to go...

Comment: If I change the interval, will the observable automatically change or is it constant? How can I have the interval dynamically controlled by a different setter?

Answer (score 4):

Small fix to Dave Moten's answer: if need it to actually work - you should NOT forget to subscribe. You should do

```
   Observable
    .interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .doOnNext(n -> task())
    .subscribe()
```